# node js parsing foreign characters

Tags: node.js, character, translate

I have a node js script that get's some data from a server and get's the readable strings.

The function I am using to convert the hex to string is the following:

```
function hex2a(hexx) {
    var hex = hexx.toString();//force conversion
    var str = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2)
        str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16));

    return str;
}
```

This works for most strings but when it comes to foreign letters I can't get it to work.

For example:

The following:
[image]

is the string that I want to be shown in the console.log cmd window.

That in hex is the following (apparently...):

> D9 87 D9 86 DA AF 20 D8 B3 D9 88 D8 A7 D8 B1 5B

And that is outputting the following in cmd:

> Ù?Ù?Ú¯ Ø³Ù?Ø§Ø±

How can I get that to work so it shows me the correct output which is what is shown in the image?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like UTF-8 to me [see reference here](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/)

One way is to escape each character with `\u` as follows, `console.log('\u00d9\u0087\u00D9');`

In node's version .12 there's [this option](https://nodejs.org/api/string_decoder.html)

There's also some really cool modules that do this for you, check out  [the utf8 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/utf8)

```
//from docs
// → '\xA9' 

utf8.decode('\xF0\x90\x80\x81');
```

Comment: would i have to change all of my console.logs or is there a way to do this in the function?